# How to flatten wrapped array in spark dataset in java

Tags: java, apache-spark

Using Spark 2.2
Java 1.8

I have a requirement to collect_set of array column. But it is giving me WrappedArray. Please see below.

```
Dataset<Row> df2 = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("values"))
df2.show(truncate=False)
# +-----+----------------------------------------------+ 
# |id|                         collect_list(values) | 
# +-----+----------------------------------------------+ 
# |1    |[WrappedArray(1, 2, 3), WrappedArray(4, 5, 6)]| 
# |2    |[WrappedArray(2), WrappedArray(3)]            | 
# +-----+----------------------------------------------+

Expected output : = 

# +-----+------------------+
# |store|           values |
# +-----+------------------+
# |1    |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
# |2    |[2, 3]            |
# +-----+------------------+
```

How can we achieve above output in spark java. Can someone help on this?.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the scala equivalent using UDF (Not a java Guy):

```
//df.show(false)

+-----+----------------------------------------------+
|store|values                                        |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
|1    |[WrappedArray(1, 2, 3), WrappedArray(4, 5, 6)]|
|2    |[WrappedArray(2), WrappedArray(3)]            |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+

import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val flattenWrappedArray = udf((value:  Seq[Seq[Int]]) => {value.flatten})
df.withColumn("values_new",flattenWrappedArray($"values")).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------+-------------+
|store|values                                        |values_new   |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+-------------+
|1    |[WrappedArray(1, 2, 3), WrappedArray(4, 5, 6)]|[1,2,3,4,5,6]|
|2    |[WrappedArray(2), WrappedArray(3)]            |[2,3]        |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible without adding a column? like df.select

Answer (score -1):

Function "explode" can be used before groupping:

```
df.withColumn("values", explode($"values")).groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"values"))
```

Comment: explode is costly operation. It is taking more time. Can have different approach?.Thanks